# AX: Print Report with settings, Paper Tray

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I'm trying to modify some settings from code.
I read some post about it, for example this HOW TO:
[TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee873254.aspx)

I can retrive the tray information, for example

```
info( strFmt("Tray1  %1     %2", printJobSettings.getTray(1),  printJobSettings.getTrayName(1) ));
info( strFmt("Tray2  %1     %2", printJobSettings.getTray(2),  printJobSettings.getTrayName(2) ));
info( strFmt("Tray3  %1     %2", printJobSettings.getTray(3),  printJobSettings.getTrayName(3) ));
```

with this result
[image]

But when I try to execute this code from TechNet

```
public static void main(Args _args){
SrsReportRunController controller = new SrsReportRunController();
SRSPrintDestinationSettings printSettings;

controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(Report1, Design1));
printSettings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
printSettings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::Printer);
printSettings.printerName('KONICA MINOLTA C3110 PS');
printSettings.printLandscape(true);
printSettings.numberOfCopies(1);
printSettings.setPaperTray(1);
printSettings.collate(true);

controller.parmShowDialog(true);
controller.startOperation();
}
```

I receive this message:
[image]

**UPDATE:**  I forgot to say, I have tested every tray.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Obvious question, but do you have paper in the manual feed of the printer?

Comment: i have paper in both. i tested every number with the same result.